# Group By clause with comma-separated values

Tags: sql-server

For my situation, I am attempting to apply the stackoverflow solution [here](http://GROUP%20BY%20clause%20to%20get%20comma-separated%20values%20[duplicate]).

Below are my tables:

Specialty:

```
Id  Dish       ChefId
1   Caviar     1
2   Caviar     2
3   Foie gras  2
4   Foie gras  3
5   Foie gras  5
6   Truffles   1
7   Truffles   4
```

Chef:

```
Id  Name
1   Jake
2   Tara
3   Oscar
4   Linda
5   Wally
```

So far, I came up with the following sql statement:

```
SELECT Dish, ChefId = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), ChefId)
        FROM Specialty s1
        WHERE s1.Dish = s2.Dish
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
    FROM Specialty s2
    GROUP BY Dish
```

With the result:

```
Dish       Chef
Caviar     1, 2
Foie gras  2, 3, 5
Truffles   1, 4
```

However, I would like to get the final result:

```
Dish       Chef
Caviar     Jake, Tara
Foie gras  Tara, Oscar, Wally
Truffles   Jake, Linda
```

Comment: post the link which was marked as a duplicate correctly

Comment: Join speciality s1 to the chef table and use the chef names rather than ids in the for xml path

Comment: You did the hard part already. To get the names is trivial, it is just a join in the query inside your STUFF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, all you need is an `INNER JOIN` onto the Chef table inside your `STUFF` statement and then you simply swap out `ChefId` with `Name`.

```
SELECT Dish, ChefId = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + c1.Name
        FROM Specialty s1
           INNER JOIN Chef c1
             ON s1.ChefId = c1.Id
        WHERE s1.Dish = s2.Dish
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
    FROM Specialty s2
    GROUP BY Dish
```

I have a working SQL Fiddle example here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b7d5/6

Comment: I tried your solution but I am getting the error `Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of stuff function.`

Comment: @TitoyKoh Updated my answer, I was on my phone before so I was guessing

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query with a cte to join the names:

```
;With Cte as (
    Select s.*, c.[Name] from #speciality S
    join #Chef c
    on s.ChefId = c.Id
) 
SELECT Dish, ChefNames = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [name]
        FROM Cte s1
        WHERE s1.Dish = s2.Dish
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
    FROM Cte s2
    GROUP BY Dish
```

Output as below:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|   Dish    |     ChefNames      |
+-----------+--------------------+
| Caviar    | Jake, Tara         |
| Foie gras | Tara, Oscar, Wally |
| Truffles  | Jake, Linda        |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: your solution works great! Just looking for a simpler solution (one without using Cte)?